# Uploading and streaming videos via silverlight

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, streaming

How would I go about doing the following:

1. I upload a video file via ASP.Net MVC application.
2. I then stream this video inside a Silverlight usercontrol.

I'd like to know the libraries and software I'll need. The workflow, and if possible, some code samples / links to samples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Stephen Walther has a great blog post about uploading videos files using ASP.NET MVC and Silverlight [here](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/10/03/asp-net-mvc-application-building-family-video-website-5-multiple-file-upload-with-progress.aspx).  If you are not committed to Silverlight for the upload control, I recommend [SlickUpload](http://krystalware.com/Products/SlickUpload/), which works in ASP.NET MVC environments.  [Here is another](http://dimebrain.com/2010/01/large-or-asynchronous-file-uploads-in-asp-net-mvc.html) recent post about handling large or asynchronous file uploads in ASP.NET MVC.
2. I have been very pleased with the [Silverlight 2 Video Player](http://www.codeplex.com/sl2videoplayer), but it only seems to stream .WMV files.

The upload component will need to place the files into a directory that can be browsed to.  That way, you can just put the url to that video in as a parameter to the video player control.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to be using: [Silverlight File Upload](http://silverlightfileupld.codeplex.com/) + [SlideShow2](http://slideshow2.codeplex.com/) to stream video to do this on a ASP.NET MVC project I'm working on.